# Why am I getting potential leak with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

Following the [StringCalculator](https://github.com/twobitlabs/xcode-katas/tree/master/Objective-C/StringCalculator) kata from [Xcode Katas](https://github.com/twobitlabs/xcode-katas), I ended up with a following class.

```
@implementation StringCalculator

- (int) add: (NSString *) string {    
    // this is marked as a potential memory leak by the `Analyze` tool
    NSMutableString *separatorCharacters = [@"\n" mutableCopy];

    if ([string hasPrefix:@"//"]) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2, 1);
        NSString *additionalSeparator = [string substringWithRange:range];
        [separatorCharacters appendString:additionalSeparator];
    } else {
        [separatorCharacters appendString:@","];
    }

    NSCharacterSet *separators = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:separatorCharacters];
    NSArray *numbers = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separators];

    // [separatorCharacters release];

    int sum = 0;    
    for (NSString *number in numbers) {
        sum += [number intValue];
    }
    return sum;
}

@end
```

Everything works fine, but when I run Analyze, I'm getting a potential memory leak on the first line of the method. If I do a manual `release` at the end, it seems to satisfy the analyzer, but I don't really understand why this is happening.

**How does creating a `mutableCopy` differ from a `substringWithRange`, for example?** I'm not sure how to check if I'm using ARC, but if I wasn't, I should be leaking memory on every single line where I create a object right?

I also thought that calling `release` is kind of deprecated or unnecessary in ARC projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I do a manual `release` at the end, it seems to satisfy the analyzer

You aren't using ARC.  Manual releasing is forbidden with ARC, this wouldn't compile.  Check your build settings.

Comment: And, for the record, you're not leaking memory on any other line because all of the other objects created are added to a thing called the autorelease pool — you have a reference to them and a guarantee about the minimum time they'll remain alive but you don't own them and so it isn't your job to dispose of them. It's a convenient mechanism for temporary values and return results which you can defer learning about if you're learning ARC first but remains a detail of the implementation underneath.